# potentiometer switch stereo

Tags: voltage, switches, potentiometer

Regarding the following potentiometer with switch can someone please tell me what is the difference between it's switch rating power and maximum operation voltage?

It's a bit too complicated for me to be honest. Can't get my head around that.

The potentiometer is supposed to be used as volume control and in addition as a power switch for my amp running with 16v. Would this one suit my needs?
http://www.alpha-product.net/Img/R1231GS.pdf

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The switch is rated at 12 V DC and 1 A.

That means it can be used on circuits up to 12 V DC and can switch currents up to 1 A.

Your circuit is 16 V which is a bit beyond it's rating. It would probably be OK if the current is a bit lower than 1 A - perhaps < 0.8 A as this reduces the load the switch has to connect / interrupt. (The arcing during switching is what causes wear and tear on the switch contacts.)

Comment: It could safely be used to operate a relay. Which might also give a satisfying thunk when energised.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know the exact A the amp draws but I will check that.
Andrew how would it work with a relay? Would the switch trigger the relay?